# subtracts the second row from the first row?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

How do I use loops to write a code that subtracts the second row from the first row?

```
for i in range(1, 201,1): 
    NHA_2_pd = NHA_1_pd.iloc[i:] - NHA_1_pd.iloc[i-1:] # corrected the indentation
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming pandas here.

If you only want to subtract the second row from the first one:

```
NHA_2_pd = NHA_1_pd.iloc[1] - NHA_1_pd.iloc[0]
```

If you also want 2-3, 3-4, etc.:

```
NHA_2_pd = NHA_1_pd.shift() - NHA_1_pd
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I did! However, I changed the order like below. because the result has the minus value.  
NHA_2_pd = NHA_1_pd.shift() - NHA_1_pd

Comment: @YoungjinKO yes of course, I updated ;)